# Only certain bootstrap glyphicons are displaying correctly, consistent results in all browsers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I know that this question has been asked a lot but I tried re-downloading Bootstrap (I've got the latest version - 3.3.6), my `@font-face{ }` has the correct paths to my font files, I don't know what else to try.  I get the same results in both Chrome and Firefox.  One thought I had is that I'm trying to put my icons w/in `<em>` tags, but when I tried moving them to outside the tags, they still looked like squiggley lines, so that didn't fix it.

I want to use `glyphicon-chevron-up` and `glyphicon-chevron-down` (which show up as ≅ and [ ) but when I do something like `<span class="caret"></span>` then it looks perfectly normal.

Here is how I am using them:

```
<em class="pull-right">
    <em class="pull-left">
        <span class="glyphicon-chevron-up" ng-click="plusOne($index)"></span><br>
        <span class="glyphicon-chevron-down" ng-click="minusOne($index)"></span>
    </em>
    {{ post.upvotes - post.downvotes }}
</em>
```

I can still click the icons and increase/decrease the vote count so I don't think it is a problem with Angular, but just for reference I am using angular1.4.9 and django1.9.  Again, I know several variations of this question have been asked but none of the solutions I found worked for me so any additional ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Do any other `glyphicon-*` icons show up? The class `caret` might be working because it is not necessarily under the `glyphicon` name.

Comment: I've tried `glyphicon-menu-up`, `glyphicon-menu-down`, `glyphicon-thumbs-up` and `glyphicon-thumbs-down` and none of those work either @SamuelDavidson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe its for this:

```
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" ng-click="plusOne($index)"></span><br>
```

In my page works great.

Just add glyphicon before the glyphicon-icon name.

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much!